# How can I save hand histories when playing on Pokernuts

Tags: hand-history, software

I play on [Pokernuts](https://www.pokernuts.eu/) because it's the only site I can play on due to regulation limitations. The problem is I can't save my hand histories and no tracking software is integrated with Pokernuts that I know of.

Is there any program that is free or reasonably priced which (via screen scraping or otherwise) allows you to save all your hand histories?

Comment: You could contact the developer for direct assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched up this room and it looks like Pokernuts is part of the WPN (winning poker network). I know from experience that Pokertracker is integrated with the winning poker network, so you should be able to use it to track your hand histories.

There are many other tracking softwares that are compatible with the WPN, so I suggest shopping around a bit on google and looking for one that you can get for cheap and that fits your needs.